# Incorrect syntax near '2' at line 11. line 11 is "@processdate" variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm getting syntax error in @processdate variable, AS per my understanding it is because of date format (sub query that is stored in @processdate variable). I need help AS I am new to sql.

I'm trying to SET all of the query in stored procedure. What I have tried - dIFferent date formats, converting @processdate variable.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rec_search_pay]
    @processdatefrom DATETIME,
    @processdateto DATETIME,
    @collectiondatefrom DATETIME,
    @collectiondateto DATETIME,
    @amount MONEY,
    @stationid VARCHAR(10), 
    @bankcode VARCHAR(2),
    @branchcode VARCHAR(6),
    @ponumber VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bank AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @branch AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @station AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @amounts AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @pono AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @processdate AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @collectiondate AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @stmt AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @linebreak AS VARCHAR(2);

    SET @linebreak = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

    SET @processdate = ' AND h.processdate >= ' + CAST(@processdatefrom AS NVARCHAR) + 
                       ' AND h.processdate <= ' + CAST(@processdateto AS NVARCHAR) 

    SET @collectiondate = ' AND h.collectiondate >= ' + CAST(@collectiondatefrom AS NVARCHAR) + 
                          ' AND h.collectiondate <= ' +  CAST(@collectiondateto AS NVARCHAR) 

    IF (@amount LIKE '%[^0-9]')
        SET @amounts = ' AND amount = ' + @amount
    ELSE
        SET @amounts = ' '

    IF (@bankcode <> '00')
        SET @bank = ' and h.bankcode = ' + @bankcode
    ELSE
        SET @bank =  ' '

    IF (@branchcode <> '0')
        SET @branch = ' and h.branchcode = ' + @branchcode
    ELSE
        SET @branch =  ' '  

    IF (@stationid <> 7)
        SET @station = ' and h.stationid = ' + @stationid
    ELSE
        SET @station =  ' ' 

    IF (@ponumber LIKE '%[^0-9]')
        SET @pono = ' and  h.advicenumber = ' + @ponumber
    ELSE 
        SET @pono =  ' '    

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @stmt = 'SELECT h.bankcode, RTRIM(bankname) AS bankname, h.branchcode, 
                        RTRIM(branchname) AS branchname, h.processdate, 
                        h.collectiondate, h.advicenumber, h.amount, h.commission, 
                        h.servicecharges, h.others, h.adjustment, s.stationname, h.userid 
                 FROM banks b, branches br, reconcile h, stations s
                 WHERE CAST(h.bankcode AS VARCHAR) = b.bankcode 
                   AND CAST(h.bankcode AS VARCHAR) = br.bankcode
                   AND CAST(h.branchcode AS VARCHAR) = br.branchcode 
                   AND h.stationid = s.stationid 
                   AND returned <> ''Y''
                 '+ @processdate + @linebreak + --problems seems to be here
             + @collectiondate + @linebreak +
             + @bank + @linebreak +
             + @branch + @linebreak +
             + @station + @linebreak +
             + @amounts + @linebreak +
             + @pono + @linebreak +
       'ORDER BY 1, 3, collectiondate'

    EXEC (@stmt)
```

Executing the stored procedure:

```
exec rec_search_pay '2018-mar-02', '2018-may-01', '2018-mar-01', 
                    '2018-apr-30', 27698, 1, 3, 2003, 4721621
```

Expected result:

```
3 /NATIONAL BANK OF PAKISTAN /2003 /C.O.D. DRIGH ROAD [2003]     
/2018-04-05 00:00:00.000 /2018-04-02 00:00:00.000 /4721621 /27698.00     
/272.00 /0.00 /0.00 /0.00 /Karachi /john
```

Actual result:

```
Incorrect syntax near '2'.
```

Stored procedure(query) using print:

```
select h.bankcode, rtrim(bankname) AS bankname, h.branchcode, 
   rtrim(branchname) AS branchname, h.processdate, h.collectiondate, 
   h.advicenumber, h.amount, h.commission, h.servicecharges, h.others, 
   h.adjustment, s.stationname, h.userid 
from banks b, branches br, reconcile h, stations s
Where cast (h.bankcode AS VARCHAR) = b.bankcode 
 and cast (h.bankcode AS VARCHAR) = br.bankcode
 and cast (h.branchcode AS VARCHAR) = br.branchcode 
 and h.stationid = s.stationid 
 and returned <> 'Y'
 and h.processdate >= Mar  2 2018 12:00AM and h.processdate <= --prob
         May  1 2018 12:00AM
     and h.collectiondate >= Mar  1 2018 12:00AM and h.collectiondate <= 
         Apr 30 2018 12:00AM
     and h.bankcode = 3
     and h.branchcode = 2003
     and h.stationid = 1

 order by 1, 3, collectiondate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify date literals in your query, the date value must be surrounded with single quotes. For example this part of your code:

```
and h.processdate >= Mar  2 2018 12:00AM
```

If you add quotes, it should become:

```
and h.processdate >= 'Mar  2 2018 12:00AM'
```

But it isn't a good idea to use date formats like this. You better use `'20180302'` for March 2nd, 2018. This will save you a lots of trouble.

Comment: i executed the stored procedure like this :                                                                  exec rec_search_pay '2018-mar-02', '2018-may-01', '2018-mar-01',  '2018-apr-30', 27698, 1, 3, 2003, 4721621   -- dates are in single quotes , Andrey the query you are talking about i porvided that as preview.

Comment: The dates in your dynamically generated query text are not quoted. Take a look at your printed output.

Comment: Dear Andrey, can tell or show me how to do that, i understood where i am wrong.

Comment: Simply add the quotes when you construct the query. Currently you are doing this: `set @processdate = ' and h.processdate >= ' + cast(@processdatefrom as nvarchar) + ' and h.processdate ...`. Add quotes before and after your date values, like this: `set @processdate = ' and h.processdate >= ''' + cast(@processdatefrom as nvarchar) + ''' and h.processdate ...`. Do it for all dates in your query. And if you think my answer was helpful, don't forget to accept and upvote it :)